# create an instance of a class by using it's string name in python

Tags: python, oop

let's say I have 4 classes.
I would like to create a single instance of a specific class, defined by input.

for example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.attr = arg

...

class E:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.attr = arg

chosen_class = input('choose your class: ')
instance1 = chosen_class(self, arg)
```

the problem is that the class name recognized as a string and the error that shown is `'str' object has no attribute`.

my question is - How can I unwrap this string in order to use it as my class name?

from this: `instance = 'A'(self)`

to this: `instance = A(self)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you create a dictionary and accept the user input as the key and the corresponding class as the value?

Comment: You have to create that mapping somehow, Generally, a `dict` would be a choice to map strings to arbitrary objects, but you could use an `if-elif-else` statement as well, for example.

Comment: This would be quite brittle. What if you change the class name? Should users need to adapt to a implementation detail like that?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.attr = arg

class B:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.attr = arg

mapping = {'A': A, 'B': B}
chosen_class = mapping[input('choose your class: ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is `eval`, but you should not actually do this:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, arg):
...         self.attr = arg
...
>>> class E:
...     def __init__(self, arg):
...         self.attr = arg
...
>>> instance1 = eval(input('choose your class: '))("foo")
choose your class: A
>>> instance1
<__main__.A object at 0x035F81D8>
```

because it's very unsafe on many levels.  Use something like a lookup dict.  For example:

```
>>> class_lookup = {
...     'A': A,
...     'E': E,
... }
>>> instance1 = class_lookup[input('choose your class: ')]("foo")
choose your class: E
>>> instance1
<__main__.E object at 0x035F8118>
```

Comment: Why put the unsafe solution before the safe and recommended one?

Comment: Because it's literally the exact thing they asked for.  I wanted to go ahead and answer their question before giving them my unsolicited advice.  :)